# Place gui elements below thumbstick in roblox

Tags: roblox

The thumbstick on lower left controls player movement in roblox for touch enabled devices. I would like to place some gui elements in that same corner (under the thumbstick) which are just for display like frames or text labels (not buttons or input elements). Its a good place in my opinion to put things that the player might want to glance at occasionally but not interact with directly.

When I place these elements it blocks the normal thumbstick behavior. The thumbstick is drawn on top of the gui elements like I want but I cant click the part of the thumbstick that is on top of other gui elements. When I inspect an active game I can see the thumbstick is at z index 1 and I put my gui elements at zindex -1 so really not sure why its blocking things.

Answer (score 0):

NM found the elements were marked selectable and active. I disabled those thumbstick works now.